# what's the differenece between finite state automaton and finite state automata

Tags: automata, finite-automata, terminology

Upon googling all I get is the definition of finite-state automaton but what's the difference between it and finite-state automata or are they the same

Comment: Automata is the plural of automaton.

Comment: (Here, the usage summary of tag `finite-automata` isn't exactly helpful.)